# Casting String to [NSObject : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need to convert a string to an NSObject : AnyObject type so that I can run it into my Parse cloud code however I am having issues as it says I cannot cover type String to an unrelated type [NSObject : AnyObject].  How can I convert this string to that.  I need to keep it a string so that I can eventually retrieve the string from a text field within my app.  Below is my code

```
    var name : String
    name = "kooshesh"
    let parameters : [NSObject : AnyObject]
    parameters = (name as? [NSObject : AnyObject])!

    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("AddFriendRequest", withParameters: parameters) { results, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Your error handling here
        } else {
            print(results)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `var name : String` is a String, and `let parameters : [NSObject : AnyObject]` is a dictionary. These are unrelated types that cannot be converted from one to the other.

More than likely, you should have a key for the parameters value so you can do something like this:

```
parameters = [ "MyKey" : name]
```